# Cluster-aware client app (to SQL Server)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, cluster-computing, clustered-index

We have an .NET client app working against SQL Server 2005 (clustered), do I need to do something special in the client app to make it cluster aware?

Answer (score 6):

No - except naturally handle server restarts. SQL Server "cluster" is "server crashed, restarts on another computer". Obviously this means you will get into trouble assuming a SQL Connection that you opened STAYS open - a cluster switch will invalidate all connections and open transactions, and you have to reopen them and restart any open work in the database.